# Rewriting multi-dimensional VLAs in C89

Tags: c, pointers, malloc, c99, c89

I'm rewriting a bunch of C99 VLAs for an open source project for support in Visual Studio. So I have a lot of statements like

```
void somefunc(double var[r]){...}
```

which I rewrite to

```
void somefunc(double *var) {
     var = malloc(sizeof(double) * r);
     ...
     free(var);
}
```

Which I am assuming to be the correct way to do this. 
The problem is I am starting to see some more complicated VLA declarations which are leaving me stumped. For example:

```
double *(*var)[length1][length2][length3] = malloc(sizeof(double *[length4][length1][length2][length3]));
```

So to me this essentially looks like a 5 dimensional array.
This is clearly illegal in C89 because of the use of variables in the `sizeof()` function.

My guess on how to rewrite this would be:

```
double *****var = malloc(sizeof(double ****) * length1);
      for(int i = 0; i<length1; i++) {
            var[i] = malloc(sizeof(double ***) * length2);
            for(int j = 0; j<length2; j++) {
                 var[i][j] = malloc(sizeof(double **) * length3);
                      for(int k = 0; k<length3; k++) {
                           var[i][j][k] = malloc(sizeof(double *) * length4);
                      } 
            }
      }
```

As messy as it is, this is my best guess on how to rewrite the above statement. Is this technically correct, and is there a better way I should be going about this?

Comment: If you have this `double *(*var)[length1][length2][length3] = malloc(sizeof(double *[length4][length1][length2][length3]));` you should rewrite all the program from the start.

Comment: I suggest you find the original developers and shoot them, unless this was meant to be a joke on their part. And as for the declaration, this is actually a pointer to a three dimensional array of `double` pointers.

Comment: @szczurcio That makes more sense, thanks. Does my guess on rewriting that still work?

Comment: There is no way to literally re-code multi-dimensional variable size arrays in C89. You can do as @szczurcio does and "fake" multi-d arrays with arrays of pointers.  But this has overhead for pointer space and potentially cache load. The more faithful transcription is to define functions and/or macros that to do the indexing arithmetic in a 1-d array and recode all the array accesses.  That is, for an MxNxP array A, you'd access element `A[i][j][k]` as `A1d[(i * N + j) * P + k]`. Of course `A1d` is allocated with `M*N*P` elements. This hassle is why vla's were added to the language!

Comment: Your conversion of that first example (with `double var[r]`) is almost certainly wrong.

Comment: It's all things considered probably easier and more productive to write a plugin for VS to use a proper C compiler instead like `clang` or MinGW version of `gcc` ...

Comment: Use the Intel or Clang compiler plugin for MSVC instead of letting Microsoft's lack of commitment to ISO language support (i.e. C99) ruin your life.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my attempt:

```
double***** var = malloc(sizeof *var * length4);

for (int i = 0; i < length4; ++i)
{
    var[i] = malloc(sizeof *var[i] * length1);

    for (int j = 0; j < length1; ++j)
    {
        var[i][j] = malloc(sizeof *var[i][j] * length2);

        for (int k = 0; k < length2; ++k)
        {
            var[i][j][k] = malloc(sizeof *var[i][j][k] * length3);

            for (int l = 0; l < length3; ++l)
            {
                var[i][j][k][l] = NULL;     
                // var[i][j][k][l] is a double* - you can allocate some room for a double here, or assign the address of an existing variable
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Similar to yours, except that note how I used `length4` in the first `malloc`. If you look at your original declaration, `var` is a *pointer* to a three dimensional array of `double*`. As we can deduce from the `malloc` call on the right, memory for `length4` such arrays is allocated, so you can think of `var` as an array of `length4` three-dimensional arrays of `double*`.

I still maintain that anyone who puts such stuff in production code ought to be shot on the spot (well, you, as a maintainer, are excused).

IIRC declaring variables inside `for`s isn't valid C89, but you can move these above to the top of your scope.

Note that, as @immibis points out in the comments, your first conversion is most likely a mistake; `double *var` is an argument to the function, which means it's passed by value, so any changes you make to it inside the function aren't visible outside, and on top of that, you `malloc` some memory, do stuff with it, then `free` it. Even if you were modifying a passed pointer - which would require the parameter type to be `double**` - it still isn't necessary to pass a variable so you can use it locally exclusively. You most likely wanted to `malloc` the memory outside of the function and pass a valid pointer (and hopefully the size) to it.

Comment: Is there a difference between saying `sizeof *var` vs `sizeof(double ****)` or is it just a matter of preference? Thanks for the help.

Comment: @EthanPavolik No, it's the same, it's really up to you (same with the parentheses, `sizeof(*var)` would also be valid`).